# why arduino mega with bluetooth works only when it connect to the pc

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

i use arduino mega 2560 and BT JY- MCU.
i connect to the BT with my android divece but the arduino not response unless it connect to the PC.
the code is really simple one - 
maybe it becouse i use:
 "char  input = Serial.read();"

please help...

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but how is the Arduino powered?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson +1 that's what I was thinking about...

Comment: To me (not being an Arduino expert by any stretch) it sounds like a power issue. Could you power it using a wall plug for testing?

Comment: please clarify; is it that it works with the BT device attached to the Arudino's TX/RX and wirelessly connected to a PC, but fails when wirelessly connected to the Andriod? Or does it work when the BT device is connected to the PC's serial. Schematic would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your Arduino sketch code. The problem might be related to Serial.read(). Hard to tell without seeing some of the sketch code. One note is that a PC USB connection can force resets that might not happen running on batteries. This can be very important (and helpful).